# If $U$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$ with $(x+y)\in U$ then is it true that $x\in U$ and $y\in U$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $U$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $x,y\in \Bbb R^n$ with $(x+y)\in U$ then is it true that $x\in U$ and $y\in U$.
It looks like it is true since x+y follows under addition, under multiplication and  the trivial solution zero vector but I would like a formal interpretation, thank you for your answers

Comment: Take $U$ to be the zero subspace.  Take $x$ to be a non zero vector.  Take $y$ to be $-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Its not true. Here is a counterexample. Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R} ^2$. Take $x=(1, 0),y=(0,1)$ and let $U=span(1,1)$. Then $x+y\in U$ but neither $x$ nor $y$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every vector subspace contains zero vector. Now let $$U=\{\lambda (1,0,0,....,0)\in \Bbb R^n :\lambda\in \Bbb R\}.$$ Then $(0,-1,0,0,....,0),(0,1,0,0,....,0)$ are not in $U$ but there sum is $(0,0,0,....,0)=0(1,0,0,....,0)\in U$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$={$(a,b)|a=b$}, $x=(1,0)$, $y=(0,1)$.